# Trie structure, lock-free inserting

Tags: c++, atomic, trie, lock-free, stdatomic

I tried to implement lock free Trie structure, but I am stuck on inserting nodes. At first I believed it was easy (my trie structure would not have any delete methods) but even swapping one pointer atomically can be tricky.
I want to swap pointer to point to structure(TrieNode) atomically only when it was nullptr so as to be sure that I do not lose other nods that other thread could insert inbetween.

```
struct TrieNode{
    int t =0;
    std::shared_ptr<TrieNode> child{nullptr};
};
   std::shared_ptr<TrieNode> root;
   auto p = std::atomic_load(&root);
   auto node =  std::make_shared<TrieNode>();
   node->t=1;


   auto tmp = std::shared_ptr<TrieNode>{nullptr};
   std::cout<<std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong( &(p->child), &tmp,node)<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<node->t;
```

With this code I get exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

EDIT: Thank you for all your coments. Maybe I did not specify my problem so I want to address it now.After around 10 hours of coding last day I changed few things. Now I use ordinarry pointers and for now it is working. I did not test it for now if its race free with multiple threads inserting words. I plan to do it today.

```
const int ALPHABET_SIZE =4;
enum  Alphabet {A,T,G,C,END};
class LFTrie{
private:
    struct TrieNode{
        std::atomic<TrieNode*> children[ALPHABET_SIZE+1];
    };
    std::atomic<TrieNode*> root = new TrieNode();
public:
void Insert(std::string word){
        auto p =root.load();
        int index;
        for(int i=0; i<=word.size();i++){

            if(i==word.size())
                index = END;
            else
                index = WhatIndex(word[i]);
            auto expected = p->children[index].load();
            if(!expected){
                auto node = new TrieNode();
                if(! p->children[index].compare_exchange_strong(expected,node))
                    delete node;
            }
            p = p->children[index];
        }
    }
};
```

Now I believe it will work with many threads inserting different words . And yes, in this solution I discard node if there next pointer is not null. Sorry for the trouble (I am not native speaker).

Comment: You may be able to do this _atomically_ but that doesn't mean _lock free_.  what does `atomic<shared_ptr<T>>::is_lock_free()` return for you?  I bet it returns false.

Comment: After I changed to ordinary pointers this method returns 1. I do not know how it was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAS pattern should be something like:

```
auto expected = p->child;
while( !expected ){
  if (success at CAS(&p->child, &expected, make_null_replace() ))
    break;
}
```

if you aren't paying attention to the return value/expected and testing that you are replacing null, stored locally, you are in trouble.

On failure, you need to throw away the new node you made.

Comment: Hi, I still get this error. And I cannot throw away new node. If other thread made the node my thread has to go to it.

Comment: I changed to ordinary pointers. And it does not print error anymore. I do not know why there was a problem with using shared pointers.

Comment: @dandon223: You don't necessarily have to discard `node` or `tmp`, just change the values in it if necessary before trying again to insert it (maybe somewhere else), if your function always keeps trying until it successfully inserts instead of returning failure.

Comment: @dandon Fundamentally, you do have to be willing to discard the node you create.  Another thread might independently be creating its own new node and even have populated it; you cannot roll back the other created stuff and be safe.  The thread that CAS's with nullptr is the one you should keep.  The other, you fall back on the "trie node already there" code path.

Comment: @peter I cannot take your advice and produce a sane implementation following what you say should be done.  Please provide a full answerso I can either see what I am missing or point out your error, not in a comment.  I mean, you *can* choose to not discard, such code is legal, but I don't see a sane way to solve the OP's trie insert if you won't discard.

Comment: If you're definitely going to eventually insert a node somewhere (and thus publish it to other threads), you can keep changing the contents of your unpublished node until you succeed at inserting it somewhere.  If that's not how this algorithm needs to work, then NVM.  I don't really understand the code in the question; it only has one child pointer so it seems to be a linked list, not a Trie, and it's inserting a new child-of-root?  Oh, but only if it was previously nullptr, hence the need to discard I guess.  I was assuming there was a Trie and you'd have to search for a new insert spot.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do not know why I created nullptr from nowhere when I could just read te child and do something if it is nullptr.